# Infinitely many roots $z e^z = a, a\neq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Spent some time trying to tackle this problem. It is supposed to use Rouche's Theorem, but not sure how.

Show that $ze^z = a$ for $a \neq 0$ has infinitely many roots.

Rouches:
(1) $f$ and $g$ analytic in and on simple, closed $C$

(2) $|f|>|g|$ on $C$

(*) $f+g$ and $f$ have the same number of zeroes inside $C$

Comment: It would be trivial using Picard's theorem. Does it have to be Rouché's theorem?

Comment: I would like to see how to use Rouche's; I've seen something similar with Picard's. Either way, I'm interested, if you care to post. @DanielFischer

Comment: So far, I'm drawing a blank on Rouché's theorem. Maybe I'll have an idea after turning off the computer.

Comment: Tried something like this:
$f = ze^z - z^2$ and $g = z^2 - a$, which yields $f+g = ze^z - a$. And knowing externally that $e^z =z$ has infinitely many roots, this could work, with one exception that we need to satisfy (2). I'm tabling this problem for now.